# iOS 13: large navigation bar not using bar tint color (defaults to white)

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, xcode11, ios13

I have an app that up to XCode 10 had the same color for the large and standard navigation bars. However, when running on XCode 11 the bar's background is white and only uses the bar tint when the bar turns to the standard size (for example, by scrolling). This is particularly a big issue since the bar buttons' tint is white, and on the large format, they don't show.

Has somebody come across this same issue, and knows how to keep the same color for the large bar as well as the standard?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you watch the WWDC videos? Navigation bars are heavily changed in iOS 13. You need to take that into account.

Comment: I did and remember something about it, but didn't expect them not to be configurable at all! Is that the case?

Comment: I have this exact problem. Is there a way to solve this? The docs don't really provide a solution.